# sqlite3 order by takes time

Tags: python, sql, select, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have tables in sqlite3 db that are located on memory mapped partition. I have select statement that looks like this with this query plan:

```
sqlite3> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT sst.prefix, 0 AS pb, sst.rate, 
sst.rate_n, sst.interval_1, sst.interval_n
FROM sch AS sst
WHERE
sst.i_workbook_id = 989 AND 
sst.prefix IN ('', '1', '19', '191', '1919', '19198') AND 
sst.activation_date <= DATETIME('now') AND 
(sst.expiration_date > DATETIME('now') OR sst.expiration_date IS NULL) AND
sst.start_time <= TIME('now') AND 
sst.end_time >= TIME('now');


0|0|0|SCAN TABLE sch AS sst (~185 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
```

Now if I add order by then his query plan hit the main tables twice and takes 4 times longer than earlier while tables is having 1.3 million rows but filtered rows are only two.

Here is the new query plan:

```
sqlite3> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT sst.prefix, 0 AS pb, sst.rate, 
sst.rate_n, sst.interval_1, sst.interval_n
FROM sch AS sst
WHERE
sst.i_workbook_id = 989 AND 
sst.prefix IN ('', '1', '19', '191', '1919', '19198') AND 
sst.activation_date <= DATETIME('now') AND 
(sst.expiration_date > DATETIME('now') OR sst.expiration_date IS NULL) AND
sst.start_time <= TIME('now') AND 
sst.end_time >= TIME('now') order by sst.prefix;     

0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE sch AS sst USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (i_workbook_id=?) (~7 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE sch AS sst USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (i_workbook_id=?) (~7 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite tries to optimize your second query by creating a temporary index on the `i_workbook_id` column.
That lookup is done multiple times because the `OR` expression cannot be optimized in a better way.
(See the [query optimizer](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) and [query planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) documentation.)

What you could try to do is to

- create an index on the `i_workbook_id` column; or to
- create an index on both the `i_workbook_id` and `prefix` columns; or to
- create a *covering* index on first these two and then all other columns mentioned in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses.